# How does the zoom level of IE factor in to subpixel rounding?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Hello StackOverflowers,

**Set Up:**

This problem is the same one that is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488960/css-divs-width-50-not-working-in-ie).  Specifically, we have:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">left</div>
  <div class="inner">right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer{
  width: 100%;
}

.inner{
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

viewed in Internet Explorer 8.  You can see a [JSBin example here](http://jsbin.com/ayojev/2/edit).

**Problem:**

As stated in the [problem referenced above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488960/css-divs-width-50-not-working-in-ie), the [subpixel rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309964/how-to-fix-internet-explorer-7-bug-when-using-percentage-widths-for-layout) that IE implements forces the right div to drop onto a new line when you resize the window and have the zoom level on IE set to 100%.  Or 150%.  Or 50%.  But **not**  75%, 125%, 95%, etc.

**Question:**

Why?  How does the zoom level factor in to the subpixel rounding problem.  **Why does setting the IE zoom level to 95% prevent the second div from getting kicked down onto a new line, regardless of how much resizing of the window is performed?**

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Think about what it means that IE always rounds up.

What if you have a zoom of 100% and the width is 701px?
50% is 350.5px, which means both 50% in IE will round up to 351px, resulting in a total width of 702px and overflowing.

Now, at 95%, what is 95% of 701px? 665.95px, which rounds up to 666px.
50% of that is 333px, which added up to account for both is 666px, oh boy! Now it works!

Of course, this all depends on the width of the window so sometimes 95% will help, other times it will actually hurt.

Comment: I guess that's where my confusion comes in.  You say `Of course, this all depends on the width of the window so sometimes 95% will help, other times it will actually hurt.`  Perhaps I didn't make it clear in the question, but I can resize the window as much as I please when the zoom is set at 95% **without** causing the div to drop down.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. It appears to correctly discard the odd pixel, when set to those specific zoom levels, in the 50% calculation... just when I think IE can't amaze in new ways. It's the gift that keeps on giving